# GME put option price going down as stock price declines...WHY?

Tags: put-options

Why would the put option price go down when the stock goes down?  3/19 $20 strike down 30% when gme stock down $50. Can someone explain why the put isn’t gaining value?

Comment: Most likely because implied volatility tanked at the same time - read the marked duplicate.

Comment: It's a conspiracy to screw you. All prices are actually set by a cabal of lizard beings.

Answer (score 2):

From the linked question in the comments, my answer there was:

> The major reason is that options gain in value when implied volatility increases and they lose value when implied volatility decreases. So if there's a large underlying price move in your put's favor (GME drops) and the put loses money, it's because there was a sharp contraction in implied volatility.

Here are some ultra simplified rough estimate numbers for the $250, $275 and $300 puts for 2/19 expiration, not meant to be accurate because that gets a bit detailed.

Their implied volatility on Friday was about 5.80% which is an insanely high number.  Right now, their IV is about 4.90%.  That's a heavy duty contraction and these 3 puts lost more than $30 of value due to the IV contraction.  Since these are 20-25 delta options, the gain in put value from GME's drop was not enough to offset the IV contraction hence they have lost value today.

Comment: If the answer is the same, the question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: The answer is a bit different but if people want to close it, it's fine by me.